# How to set dynamic column title in Metronic datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables, metronic

We are using a **Metronic** datatable and We need to set the column title dynamically.

Here is my example:

```
columns: [{
            field: "id",
            title: "#",
            sortable: !1,
            width: 40,
            textAlign: "center",
            selector: {
                class: "m-checkbox--solid m-checkbox--brand"
            }
        }, {
            field: "username",
            title: "Username"
        }, [enter image description here][1] {
            field: "sector_1",
            title: "sector_1",
            width: 70,
        },
     }]
```

We need to show title **sector_1 => 'XYZ'**

[Datatable image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV7JL.png)

Any suggestions based on official sources are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do dynamic with ajax.
example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html